# Trying to select the value that was chosen in a drop down list using the ID of the drop down list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi90e.png)I am trying to retrieve the value that was selected by the end user in a drop down list. The variable country is always null, I am using the id of the drop down list to retrieve the value that was selected by the user.

Here is the code in my view:

```
    <script>
        var country = document.getElementById("Countries");
        var value = country.options[country.selectedIndex].value;
        var text = country.options[country.selectedIndex].text;
  </script>

@Html.Label("Country", "Country")
<select name="Countries" id="Countries">
    @foreach (var country in ViewBag.countries)
    {
        <option value="@(country.country)">@(country.country)</option>
    }
</select>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```html
<label for="Country">Country</label> 
<select name="Countries" id="Countries"> 
    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option> 
    <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
</select>
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById("Countries"); 
var selected_country_value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;    
alert(selected_country_value);
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/poxijiluci/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It means you `<option value="no value here">`,  `@(country.country` have no value here ,first fix that then do what I did.

Comment: I just tried it and I get the following error for the second line:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Comment: my countries drop down list is already filled out with countries that I am retrieving from a ViewBag, it is not an empty list. Here is what I get when I click on View Page source:                                                              
         <label for="Country">Country</label>    
         <select name="Countries" id="Countries">
            <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
            <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
            <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
           
            ...
         </select>

Comment: @Mouna, See it now, It had just a `typo`. I just miss used `e` to `element` and let me know is it working or not?

Comment: I saw your typo and I fixed it earlier it's still not working

Comment: @Mouna have you try to run the code of Stackoverflow.com that I posted.

Comment: I ran the new code that you posted, the one where you write down the countries instead of retrieving them from the ViewBag and it's still not working

Comment: your `js` code is after your `html`? Now I think that you put the `html`  after `js` but you are trying to get the countries from `js` before the `html` rendered on the document. Put the `js` after the `html` view and try again.

Comment: you were right my js code was misplaced, it's working now! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Mouna glad finally it works for you. Best of luck :)